# Insert one more union to a union-of-tables view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a large view that consists of 'UNION ALL's of a dozen tables. This view should be "updated" to cover a couple of new tables into the union: is there a neat way to add one more table to the mix, without reintroducing all the older unions again? It's gonna be painful as there could be customized installations around.

The view is something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW vw_union (a,b,c)
AS
SELECT a,b,c from TABLE_FOO
UNION ALL
SELECT a,b,c from TABLE_BAR
UNION ALL
SELECT a,b,c from TABLE_FEZ;
```

Comment: What sort of customisations (and why)? People have added their own tables to the view, or additional columns, or filters? For the first one you could do a view on top of a view (which is just going to have its own problems later), or extract the DDL for each installation and append your new tables before running. For the others your new 'standard' code might not be compatible with what they already have. Of course, if the customisations aren't sanctioned you can just overwrite them...

Comment: @AlexPoole, I'm not even sure about the nature of these customisations. Very likely they include domain-exclusive tables included in the unions, mostly. The migrators probably have their way of dealing with this, I'm just curious if there's an elegant way to handle this.

Comment: If they've customised the view, they can jolly well re-customize it after you've made the change, I reckon.